Java. Как с помощью Unit test протестировать Eureka server?
Подскажете, как с помощью Unit test протестировать Eureka server, что вообще можно протестировать?) То что сервисы регистрируются в нем? Как это сделать?))

Никак, юнит тесты тестируют небольшой кусочек кода, они не тестируют сервера. Для серверов надо писать интеграционые тесты, системные тесты, нагрузочные тесты и тд. Но вообще непонятно зачем вам тестировать Eureka, не ясен смысл этого.

Как я понял это необходимо для ci/cd.

Ci/cd - это просто место где тесты запускать, оно не отвечает на вопрос зачем тестировать эврику
